# responsive 3-columns layout with third column having fixed size

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to create a simple element consisting of 3 columns, the 3. column being an `icon-image`.
I want the element to be responsive, but the `icon-image` should always have the same size (e.g. 40x40 px).
So, the 1. and 2. column should have % values, the 3. column should have width 40px. I don't want the `icon-image` to resize on smaller screens. The icon should always have width 40px.

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
}

.text1 {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

.text2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  float: right;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <p class="text1">Some Titel</p>

  <h3 class="text2">Some Text and some more text...</h3>

  <img src="image1.jpeg" alt="" class="image" />

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mkrizanek/usfmk6r7

Kind regards,
Milan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tweaked a little bit with **HTML** and **CSS**. But I hope you will get the logic. I have changed the `display-type` of `container` to `flex`. You can change the `with` of elements inside container as per your requirements.

```css
.container {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
}

.text {
  background-color: #BBBBBB;
  width: 50%;
}

.heading {
  background-color: #999999;
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  max-width: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">Some Text</p>
  <h3 class="heading">Heading</h3>
  <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png" class="image" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is probably to use flex.

Set "display: flex; justify-content: space-between" on the container div, and "flex: 1;" on each section that you want responsive.

If you want the text in the second div to push all the way to the image, you can also add "text-align: right;" to it.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.text1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.text2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.image {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #088;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <p class="text1">Some Title</p>

  <h3 class="text2">Some Text and some more text...</h3>

  <img alt="" class="image" />

</div>
```

Here is a good resource for flexbox:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Can I also use %-values for the width of text1 and text2? I tried, and it doesn't seem to work... I also need to be able to control margin/padding of text1 and text2...

Comment: You can change the percentage allotted to each section with the flex value (so "flex: 3"/"flex: 1" in .text1/.text2 would give 75%/25% widths).  Margin and padding should work as usual.  I added a link to a good flexbox guide.